# completar con ceros a la izquierda

Tags: php, mysql, sql

tengo esta tabla en Mysql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito completar con ceros a la izquierda hasta llegar a 5 caracteres, solo aplicaría para aquellas referencias que no tengan mas de 5 caracteres tengo este query:

```
tep_db_query("update ".TABLE." set referencia = '??' where CHAR_LENGTH(referencia) =4");

tep_db_query("update ".TABLE." set referencia = '??' where CHAR_LENGTH(referencia) =3"); 

tep_db_query("update ".TABLE." set referencia = '??' where CHAR_LENGTH(referencia) =2");

tep_db_query("update ".TABLE." set referencia = '??' where CHAR_LENGTH(referencia) =1");
```

que instrucción debo implementar en el ***set referencia*** para que el update de pinte este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las que sean mayor o igual a 5 caracteres quedan igual, solo aplica a las menores de 5 caracteres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lo puedo probar ahora pero mira a ver si te funciona usando la función LPAD: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

```
tep_db_query("update ".TABLE." set referencia = LPAD(referencia, 5, '0') where CHAR_LENGTH(referencia) =4");
```

La función acepta como parámetros una cadena, el número de caracteres que tiene que tener como mínimo la cadena resultante, y el carácter a rellenar por la izquierda en caso de que tenga menos caracteres de los que se solicitan. En tu caso quieres 5 caracteres mínimo y rellenar con el caracter '0'.

Otra opción que tienes, si puedes alterar la estructura de la tabla, es marcar la columna referencia como entero y modificador ZEROFILL. Échale un vistazo a esto por si te puede interesar o no: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

Antes de añadirlo a la base de datos, puedes darle formato al número con el método str_pad. Sería algo así:

```
$number = 5;
$numberFormat = str_pad($number, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);  // Salida: "005"
```

- Parámetro 1: tu variable con el número.
- Parámetro 2: el número de veces que se va a repetir el tercer parámetro.
- Parámetro 3: el caracter que se va a repetir tantas veces como lo definido en el parámetro 2.
- Parámetro 4: la orientación del relleno: a la izquierda, derecha...